# Modifying text and grabbing the Newest dates

Tags: php

Im working with someone else's code.

lets say I have an id have something like this in a csv text file(no header this is just an example and is imported into a database)

```
|id|partNumber|vendorNumber|dateModified|
123|18-302|fe32l|8/27/2020
123|18-302|fe32l|8/22/2020
123|18-302|fe32l|8/27/2021
321|18-3032|fe32l|8/27/2020
321|18-3032|fe32l|5/24/2022
```

My conclusion is because it gabs everything, rather than the newest, as a result it doesn't import the newest information.

**Question**
How do I modify the text file it creates to only write then newest dates for each id.(which is the first and last field in the text file). It can even delete the fields after it writes it.

I think the file is created within lines 253-297

```
 protected function writeImportFile($tmpFile)
    {

        $data = file_get_contents($tmpFile);
        $data = str_replace('\\', '', $data);
        $data = str_replace("\t", '', $data);
        file_put_contents($tmpFile, $data);
        unset($data);

        $stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        $stopwatch->start('write');
        $tmpDir = $this->tmpDir;
        $fileImport = $tmpDir . $this->tableName . '.txt';

        $fileRead = new \SplFileObject($tmpFile);
        $reader = new CsvReader($fileRead, '|');
        $reader->setHeaderRowNumber(0);

        $writer = new CsvWriter('|');
        $writer->setStream(fopen($fileImport, 'w'));

        $numLines = $reader->count();

        $i=0;
        $this->modColumns();
        foreach ($reader as $row) {

            $newRowArray = $this->modRow($row);
            if (!empty($newRowArray)) {
                $writer->writeItem($newRowArray);
            }


            $i++;
            if($i%1000 == 0){
                $this->writeLog('  import file has wrote '.$i.' of '.$numLines);
            }
        }

        unlink($tmpFile);
        $exTime = $stopwatch->stop('write');
        $timeMil = $exTime->getDuration();
        $this->writeLog('  Time to write import file for ' . $this->tableNameSw . ' ' . gmdate("H:i:s", $timeMil / 1000));
        return $fileImport;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to implement these new requirements yourself before posting in accordance with [ask]? Can you share that attempt here as a [mre], along with an explanation of where you're getting stuck in the attempt?

Comment: @esqew I have tried that. If it get really detailed my post gets down voted for some reason. Its happened every time I have posted on my other account. I haven't attempted anything because I don't know how to program in php, just a basic understanding.

Comment: "*I haven't attempted anything because I don't know how to program in php*" If you don't have the fundamental knowledge to make an attempt at helping yourself first, Stack Overflow is unfortunately not for you at this juncture - we won't write your code for you. If you have requirements that you need turned into a working end product, you should hire a developer.

Comment: @esqew I do have fundamental knowledge I have attempted to help myself on this issue and have done my fair share of research on trying to solve this issue. I do know C++ and the syntax is somewhat similar. And I have modified portions of this code prior to this. I'm not asking anyone to "write my code" cause first off its not mine to begin with. Second this is in a production environment and this code is massive I'm asking help on what about 40 lines, and third the loopholes I found dealing with this doesn't work. I'm just asking for help no need be hyper-critical.